# Why this happens when there is a condition prevents it

Tags: python, arrays, loops, if-statement, arraylist

```py
x = int(input("Enter number of NO.s"))

Numbers=[]
for i in range (x):
    Numbers.append(int(input()))

for i in range(x):
    if(i==x) :
        break
    if(Numbers[i]>=Numbers[i+1]) :

#IndexError: list index out of range ////

        temp=Numbers[i]
print(temp)
```

Comment: On the very last index of ```Numbers```, ```Numbers[i+1]``` doesn't exists giving an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't in fact have a condition to prevent the error. What you meant was either this:

```py
for i in range(x):
    if i == x - 1:
        break
    if Numbers[i] >= Numbers[i + 1]:
```

or better:

```py
for i in range(x - 1):
    if Numbers[i] >= Numbers[i + 1]:
```

Comment: I would appreciate an up-vote if that's possible.